# ASP.NET MVC Done Right: ValidateModelState loses Query Parameters using ValidateModelStateAttribute

Tags: asp.net-mvc, post-redirect-get

using [Ben Foster Automatic Validate Model State](http://ben.onfabrik.com/posts/automatic-modelstate-validation-in-aspnet-mvc) I have this code :

```
[ImportModelStateFromTempData]
public ActionResult Edit(int id, int otherProperty) {
    // ...
    return View()
}

[HttpPost,ValidateModelState]
public ActionResult Edit(int id, PaymentOrderCreateUpdateCommand order) {
    // ...
    return RedirectToAction("Index", new {otherProperty = order.otherProperty}
}
```

Being on the url :

```
/Edit/5?otherProperty=4
```

If a fill a some form that post to Edit [HttpPost] action with an invalid model state, the ValidateModelState do it's thing and returns the request to

```
/Edit/5
```

problem is the ?otherProperty=4 needed for that view to be generated is lost in the Redirect.

Anyone knows of a way to modify the automatic model state validation attribute so it includes the query parameters on it ?

for completion on the question I add the ValidateModelStateAttribute class :

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class | AttributeTargets.Method, AllowMultiple = false, Inherited = true)]
public class ValidateModelStateAttribute : ModelStateTempDataTransfer {
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext) {
        if (!filterContext.Controller.ViewData.ModelState.IsValid) {
            if (filterContext.HttpContext.Request.IsAjaxRequest()) {
                ProcessAjax(filterContext);
            } else {
                ProcessNormal(filterContext);
            }
        }

        base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
    }

    protected virtual void ProcessNormal(ActionExecutingContext filterContext) {
        // Export ModelState to TempData so it's available on next request
        ExportModelStateToTempData(filterContext);

        // redirect back to GET action
        filterContext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult(filterContext.RouteData.Values);
    }

    protected virtual void ProcessAjax(ActionExecutingContext filterContext) {

        var errors = filterContext.Controller.ViewData.ModelState.ToSerializableDictionary();
        var json = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(errors);
        // send 400 status code (Bad Request)
        filterContext.HttpContext.Response.TrySkipIisCustomErrors = true;
        filterContext.HttpContext.Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.BadRequest;
        filterContext.HttpContext.Response.StatusDescription = "Invalid Model State";
        filterContext.Result = new ContentResult() { Content = json };
    }
}
```

Comment: Not a fan of this approach: 1. It violates the separation of concerns, as part of the purpose of the controller is to handle things like model validation. 2. It makes debugging a nightmare.

Comment: I'm a fan of this approach :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

adding this to the ProcessNormal :

```
// add query string values.
var qs = filterContext.HttpContext.Request.QueryString;
foreach (string key in qs.Keys) {
    filterContext.RouteData.Values.Add(key, qs.Get(key));
}
```

looks like it does the trick. I'm not sure if this is ok or can be a problem tho.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use RouteValues instead of query parameters, and change your routes accordingly.
For example:

```
routes.MapRoute(
            name: "",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}/{p1}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional,p1 = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
```

That way you can recieve id and p1 parameters.
Using your tweak to [ValidateModelState] it's important to remember that you need to pass query parameters with routeArgument. If you use @Html.HiddenFor, they won't be in query string.